# Need help understanding MEF

Tags: c#, interface, mef

I'm trying to understand how to use MEF.

Could someone point me to or provide an example of loading multiple .dlls from a directory.
Each of those dlls will have the same void method. void start().
There are no values that need to be returned.

Also I would need to make sure the .dlls are ment to be in the folder and not try to load/run if they don't belong.

Thanks

Comment: have you done a google search on `MEF` I would personally start there

Comment: Dude your question is not in an appropiate format for StackOverflow, but yet, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=130)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this tutorial , it's very simple

link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432069/Simple-MEF-Application-for-Beginners

For inderstand interest of MEF, i suggest you to read article about `PRISM WPF Development With MEF`

I published article about subject, link : http://aghilasyakoub.wordpress.com/category/mef-managed-extensibility-framework/